# Is there a function for a sinc curve with increasing frequency at the tails?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, signal-processing

The idea is to simulate a signal with lower amplitude and higher frequency as we move away from zero in the positive and negative directions:

[image]

I am trying to find, perhaps, a modification of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}.$ The function needs to be even.

---

Thank you very much for the suggestions in the comments, but when I plot $\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}$ I get some ugly flattened wave in the middle:

[image]

---

I am looking for something like a modified sinc function as suggested in the comments, combined with a Gaussian, but without the big peak in the middle. See for instance

$$\sin(x^2)/x^2 +  \exp(-x^2) $$

[image]

Another - not completely satisfactory - equation $(-\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} + 2\frac{\cos(x^2)}{x^2})$:

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with simply using $\frac{\sin x}x$?

Comment: @lioness99a I want the frequency of oscillation to increase at the tails. The sinc function dampens the amplitude, but does not increase the frequency as $x$ increases in absolute value.

Comment: Does $\frac{sin(x^3)}{x^3}$ fit in?

Comment: @Pseudocoder. I was just typing $\frac {sin(x^a)}{x^b}$ ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Oops.. What a coincidence!

Comment: @Pseudocoder. In French, we have an expression which is almost *great minds meet*.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Although your suggestion clearly fulfills the requisites of tapering amplitude and frequency (thanks!), it does not yield a plausible simulation of a diamond-shaped signal, which is what I need (see edit to OP).

Comment: @Claude That's a really delicate expression  :>

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plot of $\cos(12x^2) \cdot e^{-x^2}$: [image: plot of cos(12x^2)*exp(-x^2)]

Instead of dividing by $x$, which causes a lot of unnecessary issues, just use $\cos$ to start. Then multiply it by whatever envelope you'd like.

Comment: I need the peak at zero to be more slender and less truncated.

Comment: Then pick a different envelope function!

Answer (score 0):

It could work by changing the input of an even oscillating function (cosine) by including a monotonously increasing function such as a logarithmic function truncated below $1.$ This would increase the frequency progressively. An exponential envelop would take care of the tapering:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
3\cos(8\log_2(\vert x\vert+1)x)e^{-\frac x 2}\quad x>0\\[2ex]
3\cos(8\log_2(\vert x\vert+1)x)e^{\frac x 2}\quad x<0
\end{cases}$$

[image]